# Decoding messages sent/received by Python websocket client

Tags: python, binary, encodings

I am using the websocket module for my client in python3, and I am trying to troubleshoot some errors I am getting that lead to the client disconnecting after seemingly random intervals.
When I enabled trace with `websocket.enableTrace(True)` I can see some entries that I am not sure how to decrypt. Here is an example:

`Thread-3:send: b'\x88\x82\xc1$\xf7\xa6\xc2\xcc'`

Any idea how to decrypt the message and see if this could explain the source of my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: If the trace contains all the data you can try to restore the byte by [unescaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10944965/150978) the printed byte-strings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't seem to be the right encoding - I am getting `'\x88\x82Á$÷¦ÂÌ'`

Comment: May be you should not print the unescaped output and instead save it to a binary file and look at it using a hex editor.

Comment: Can you post more example entries?

Comment: Are you using TLS?